Is it possible to render a button only once on Flutter Flame game screen?
I'm trying to develop a game. I want 6 hexagonal buttons on the bottom of the game screen. However, they are rendered thousands times each second. I don't want this. I want them rendered only once. Is it possible? How? Please, help me.
import 'dart:math';
import 'package:flame/components.dart';
import 'package:flame/events.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class HexagonalShape extends PositionComponent with TapCallbacks {
  late List<HexagonButton> buttons;

  @override
  Future<void> onLoad() async {
    buttons = List.generate(6, (index) {
      final centerX = size.x / 2 + 100 * cos(index * pi / 3);
      final centerY = size.y - 100 * sin(index * pi / 3);

      return HexagonButton(
        onTap: () {
          print('Button $index tapped!');
        },
        centerX: centerX,
        centerY: centerY,
        radius: 50,
      );
    });

    addAll(buttons);
  }
}

class HexagonButton extends PositionComponent with TapCallbacks {
  final Function() onTap;
  final double centerX, centerY, radius;

  HexagonButton({
    required this.onTap,
    required this.centerX,
    required this.centerY,
    required this.radius,
  });

  @override
  void render(Canvas canvas) {
    final path = Path();

    final vertices = [
      Offset(centerX - radius, centerY),
      Offset(centerX - radius / 2, centerY - radius * 0.866),
      Offset(centerX + radius / 2, centerY - radius * 0.866),
      Offset(centerX + radius, centerY),
      Offset(centerX + radius / 2, centerY + radius * 0.866),
      Offset(centerX - radius / 2, centerY + radius * 0.866),
    ];

    path.moveTo(vertices[0].dx, vertices[0].dy);
    for (int i = 1; i < vertices.length; i++) {
      path.lineTo(vertices[i].dx, vertices[i].dy);
    }
    path.close();

    print(
        "HexagonButton centerX: $centerX, centerY: $centerY, radius: $radius");

    canvas.drawPath(path, Paint()..color = Colors.red);
  }

  @override
  void onTapDown(TapDownEvent event) {
    onTap();
  }
}


I try to different combination of onLoad, onMount, paint, render functions but everytime it failed.

They are rendered 60 times per second, and that's how most game engines work.
What you can do here to optimize it, is to create the vertices list and Paint object in onLoad instead so that they don't have to be recreated every tick:
class HexagonButton extends PositionComponent with TapCallbacks {
  final Function() onTap;
  final double centerX;
  final double centerY;
  final double radius;

  final path = Path();
  final paint = Paint()..color = Colors.red;

  HexagonButton({
    required this.onTap,
    required this.centerX,
    required this.centerY,
    required this.radius,
  });

  @override
  Future<void> onLoad() async {
    final vertices = [
      Offset(centerX - radius, centerY),
      Offset(centerX - radius / 2, centerY - radius * 0.866),
      Offset(centerX + radius / 2, centerY - radius * 0.866),
      Offset(centerX + radius, centerY),
      Offset(centerX + radius / 2, centerY + radius * 0.866),
      Offset(centerX - radius / 2, centerY + radius * 0.866),
    ];

    path.moveTo(vertices[0].dx, vertices[0].dy);
    for (int i = 1; i < vertices.length; i++) {
      path.lineTo(vertices[i].dx, vertices[i].dy);
    }
    path.close();
    
    print(
        "HexagonButton centerX: $centerX, centerY: $centerY, radius: $radius");
  }

  @override
  void render(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
  }

  @override
  void onTapDown(TapDownEvent event) {
    onTap();
  }
}

If you're doing expensive operations in the render method you can use the Snapshot mixin, but that is not needed here.
